# Setting a custom origin header in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, in which the user needs to log in to use the app, However the backend needs a origin custom.mywebsite.com in order to process a request. Is there a way to set or define a origin for my extension.

Comment: Yes, see examples of using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders for new Chrome (they should have `'extraHeaders'` parameter).